# Why this solution to "Clone a linked list with next and random pointer" is O(1) Space complexity?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, big-o, space-complexity

Given a linked list having two pointers in each node. The first one points to the next node of the list, the other pointer is random and can point to any node of the list. Write a program that clones the given list in O(1) space, i.e., without any extra space.

The answer given [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clone-linked-list-next-random-pointer-o1-space/):

1. insert copyNode in between each node.
2. Then copy the random pointer to Original->next (which is the copied).

solution:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list with a random pointer.
 * class RandomListNode {
 *     int label;
 *     RandomListNode next, random;
 *     RandomListNode(int x) { this.label = x; }
 * };
 */
public class Solution {
    /**
     * @param head: The head of linked list with a random pointer.
     * @return: A new head of a deep copy of the list.
     */
    public RandomListNode copyRandomList(RandomListNode head) {
        RandomListNode cur = head;
        //insert copy in between nodes
        while(cur != null)
        {
            RandomListNode copy = new RandomListNode(cur.label);
            //1->1'->2
            copy.next = cur.next;
            cur.next = copy;
            cur = cur.next.next;
        }
        cur = head;
        //assign random to copy
        while(cur != null)
        {
            RandomListNode copy = cur.next;
            //random.next is the copy of random
            if(cur.random != null)
            {
                copy.random = cur.random.next;
            }
            cur = cur.next.next;
        }

        RandomListNode dummy = new RandomListNode(0);
        cur = head;
        RandomListNode copyPre = dummy;

        while(cur != null)
        {
            RandomListNode copyNode = cur.next;
            //split and reconnect w/ original next node
            cur.next = copyNode.next;
            //connect the copied node
            copyPre.next = copyNode;
            copyPre = copyNode; //iterates copy
            cur = cur.next; //iterates
        }

        return dummy.next;
    }
}
```

Now I see new extra space being created, by the copy. Which looks like Space: O(N).

Can someone explain why this is Space: O(1)?

Comment: I think he means that apart from the copied data, the auxiliary data should only occupy O(1) space

Comment: Please put code or pseudo-code directly in your question.  Describing an algorithm in English can be very ambiguous.  Also, questions on SO should be self-contained.  Otherwise, if the hyperlink evaporates someday your question will be incomprehensible to future readers.

Comment: @Hoblovski Thanks for the answer, can you please explain how auxiliary only occupy O(1)? Is it because linked-list only points to 1 space at a time?

Comment: @YongdingLiu Which auxiliary space is used by the algorithm apart from the copied nodes?

Comment: Why isn't copied data counts?

Comment: Otherwise the question does not make sense. Any algorithm making a clone will of course need the O(n) space for the clone itself.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the original source data (o(n)) and the resulting data (also o(n)), the algorithm only uses o(1) auxiliary data.